# Randomize order of a MongoDB query in Go

Tags: mongodb, go, random, slice, mgo

Here is my query :

```
c := session.DB("searchV").C("video")
var results []BadVideo
err5 := c.Find(nil).All(&results)
fmt.Println("request done")
if err5 != nil {
    panic(err5)
}
var i = 0
for _,badvideo := range results {
}
```

I would like to randomize the order of browsing the items of the query for making operation on each item of the request ...

So each time I run it, I browse it in a different order.

Comment: Do you want mongo to randomize the data or do you want this to happen in Golang?  The mongo $sample selector might be what you are looking for.  https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#definition

Comment: I would prefer in golang but sample could be fine for me , but  i would love an example with mgo thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Manual shuffling

Here's a simple shuffle algorithm, which shuffles (randomizes) a `[]BadVido` slice:

```
func shuffle(r []BadVideo) {
    for i := len(r) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
        j := rand.Intn(i + 1)
        r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
    }
}
```

So after you loaded your results, simply call `shuffle(results)` on it.

For testing, I will use a simple `BadVideo` type:

```
type BadVideo struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    results := []BadVideo{{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {"e"}}
    shuffle(results)
    fmt.Println(results)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZFbH32Nqnw)):

```
[{c} {d} {b} {e} {a}]
```

**How it works:**

To shuffle a slice, the `shuffle()` function randomly selects one element from the slice for each index. It does it like iterating over all elements downward, and selects a random element from the remaining slice (including index of the element we're currently selecting, because random orders also include ones where an element "stays in place"), and using a random index to swaps the element with the chosen random one. The loop goes until `i > 0` (and not until `i >=0`), because if only 1 element left, no need to swap it with itself.

#### Using `rand.Perm()`

Another variant of `shuffle()` could take advantage of [`rand.Perm()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Perm) which returns a slice containing shuffled numbers. We can use these random numbers to tell how to reorder the results:

```
func shuffle(r []BadVideo) {
    r2 := append([]BadVideo(nil), r...)
    for i, j := range rand.Perm(len(r)) {
        r[i] = r2[j]
    }
}
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kowmP2FWeB).

One thing to note here: before we do the reordering, we have to save the original slice (make a copy of it), so we can select the original elements specified by random indices when writing the results in the slice. I created a copy by appending the complete slice to a `nil` slice.